# call different functions for list elements

Tags: python, list

Have a list with numeric strings, like so:

```
numbers = ['1.2', '5.6', '1'];
```

Would like to convert first two list elements to float, and last element to int:

```
numbers = [1.2, 5.6, 1];
```

Is there any one liner/elegant way of doing?

currently I'm doing with:

```
numbers = [ float(x) for x in numbers ]
numbers[-1] = int(numbers[-1])
```

or

```
functions = [float, float, int]
results = [func(arg) for func, arg in zip(functions, numbers)]
```

Comment: What's wrong with turning everything into a `float`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I need last element to be `int` for another predefined function.